Estimation of parameters for modelling case-control samples with logistic regression

This question is inspired through the "Statistical Learning with Python" (Stanford) course offered at Edx.

Consider a two-outcomes (0 & 1) is modelled as $$\Pr(Y=1\mid X)=\frac{e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+...+\beta_pX_p}}{1+e^{\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+...+\beta_pX_p}}$$
For a given sample of cases (Y=1) and control (Y=0) used to model the probability of receiving $Y=1$ in the real world, why is it said that the regression parameters $\beta_j$ can be estimated accurately, whereas the constant term $\beta_0$
estimated through the case-control sample is incorrect, and the correct estimation for $\beta_0$ is given as: $$\hat{\beta_0^*}=\hat{\beta_0}+\log(\frac{\pi}{1-\pi})-\log(\frac{\tilde{\pi}}{1-\tilde{\pi}})$$
where $\pi$ represents the probability of getting $Y=1$ in the real-world and $\tilde{\pi}$ represents the probability of getting $Y=1$ in the case-control sample.


Where are you struggling or what's unclear? From the first bullet in the slide it should follow that the intercept will only estimate the overall prevalence if the sampling scheme reflects the population, which in case-control is almost never true (you'd usually enrich for cases). Because you have more cases you overestimate the overall proportion like so, but any further relative changes in odds are still accurately estimable.
